# Lcd displaying old data with new data

Tags: eclipse-cdt, display, overwrite, xbee, lcd

I have interfaced a programmable xbee with a 16x2 character LCD. I transmit wireless frames with the the help of another xbee and display it on the recieving xbee.
The problem arises when I send two wireless frames one after another.
Consider that I send 24 characters in the first frame, that will be displayed normally as it should be(with a random extra character at the end of the display which I dont know why)
The problem arises when I send a second frame which is smaller than the first frame for eg. of 6 characters. The LCD displays the the 6 characters but adds further 18 characters that were there in the first frame after the 6 characters.
The display looks likes this:

Frame1 display : This is a check message.
Frame2 display : Hello!s a check message. (original message : Hello!)

I tried clearall() lcd function between frames at different positions but it does not work. I also different things you see in the code but they dont work.

The code  currently looks like this;

```
  #include <xbee_config.h>

  #include <types.h>

  #include <string.h>

  #include <ctype.h>

  #define char_lcd_writ_str(a)      char_lcd_writ(a, strlen(a))

   static uint8_t test_stage = 0;
   static uint8_t test_stage_done = 0;
   static const char str[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345";

   #if defined(RTC_ENABLE_PERIODIC_TASK)
    void rtc_periodic_task(void)
   {
test_stage++;
if (test_stage == 8)
    test_stage = 0;
test_stage_done = 0;
  }
  #endif

 #ifdef ENABLE_XBEE_HANDLE_RX
  int xbee_transparent_rx(const wpan_envelope_t FAR *envelope, void FAR       *context)
  {

int c=0;
char addrbuf[ADDR64_STRING_LENGTH];
char_lcd_init(CHAR_LCD_CFG);
char_lcd_clear();

addr64_format(addrbuf, &envelope->ieee_address);
sys_watchdog_reset();

while (c<4)
{
char_lcd_writ_str(envelope->payload);
delay_ticks(2*HZ);
    
    char_lcd_clear();
    char_lcd_goto_xy(0, 0); 
    c++;
    
    }


  }
   #endif



  void main(void)
  {
   uint8_t i, j;



sys_hw_init();
sys_xbee_init();
sys_app_banner();

char_lcd_init(CHAR_LCD_CFG);

for (;;) {
    if (!test_stage_done) {
        switch (test_stage) {
        
            
        case 0:
            char_lcd_goto_xy(0, 0);
            char_lcd_writ_str("All working fine");
        
            break;
        }
        test_stage_done = 1;
    }

    sys_watchdog_reset();
    sys_xbee_tick();
  }
 }

ssize_t char_lcd_writ(const uint8_t *data, size_t len)
 {
   size_t written = 0;


while (written < len) {
    char_lcd_putchar(*data++);
    written++;
    
    if ( written == 32 || written == 64  || written == 96 || written == 128 || written == 160  || written == 192 )
    {
        delay_ticks(2*HZ);
        char_lcd_clear();
        char_lcd_goto_xy(0, 0);     
    }
    }
while (written < len) {
written = 0;
memset(*data++, '\0', len);
written++;
}
return (ssize_t)written;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be as simple as `envelope->payload` not being null-terminated and actually containing those extra characters if you go beyond the payload length specified in the envelope.  Try using your `char_lcd_writ()` function with the payload's length instead of `char_lcd_writ_str()` which will use `strlen()` to find the length.